# BroadCast Receiver gps turn on/off message information

Tags: android, gps, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi

i created a broadcast receiver for get information gps turn on or off in android.
code used:

```
public class GpsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
               Log.i("DIGICERTO","ALTEROU GPS");
            }
    }

}
```

I got no response log , why ?

Comment: Please show where and how you are registering this `BroadcastReceiver`, and please explain how you are testing it.

Comment: <code> <receiver android:name="com.digicerto.service.GpsReceiver"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> </intent-filter> </receiver></code> my testing, if turn on or off gps, no log view.

Answer (score 0):

you have to register this receiver on manifest with intent-filter
android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED

Comment: <receiver android:name="com.digicerto.service.GpsReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
       </receiver>

Comment: Yes i am  <receiver android:name="com.digicerto.service.GpsReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
       </receiver>